# Collection of images for specific points without exceeding memory in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, point, filter, google-earth-engine-python-api, memoryerror

I've been using your help for months now but today it's my time to ask my first question. I have been working with a collection of images for 4 years for small areas and developed a script that filters specific pixels and keeps only the ones that fulfill certain criteria (mostly indices and cloud conditions). I'm working on bare soil products and my task now is to use a similar script for points this time. I have 3,000 points all over the US and I'm looking to collect the images for each one of them from 2017 to 2022, filter the clouds and the indices throughout these 5 years and finally keep the median of the pixel values for the time series of each point. The median cannot be first since it might be a value that doesn't fulfill the conditions.  **My problem is the memory error** since, I think, GEE collects the tiles for each point for the whole period and then crops the pixel value for each point and that requires high memory.

I'm looking for a way to collect directly the pixel values that fulfil the conditions to reduce the memory use. Below, I have the code for the code to collect the images and mask the clouds. For time purposes, let's say the second condition is the NDVI value to be less than 0.3.

```
# Define the parameters
START_DATE = '2018-01-01'
END_DATE = '2022-10-30'
CLOUD_FILTER = 20
CLD_PRB_THRESH = 30
NIR_DRK_THRESH = 0.15
CLD_PRJ_DIST = 1
BUFFER = 50
```

Generate random points within the United States:

```
num_points = 3000  # Adjust as needed
us_region = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
    [[[-125, 49], [-125, 25], [-66, 25], [-66, 49]]], None, False
)

# Function to generate random points within a bounding box
def generate_random_points(geometry, num_points):
    return ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints(geometry, num_points)

aoi = generate_random_points(us_region, num_points)
```

#First function to collect data and cloudless.

```
def get_s2_sr_cld_col(aoi, start_date, end_date):
    # Import and filter the clouds for Sentinel 2.
    s2_sr_col = (ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
        .filterBounds(aoi)
        .filterDate(start_date, end_date)
        .filter(ee.Filter.lte('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', CLOUD_FILTER)))

    # Import and filter s2cloudless. Cloudless is a different collection than s2_sr
    s2_cloudless_col = (ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_CLOUD_PROBABILITY')
        .filterBounds(aoi)
        .filterDate(start_date, end_date))

    # Join the filtered s2cloudless collection to the SR collection by the 'system:index' property.
    return ee.ImageCollection(ee.Join.saveFirst('s2cloudless').apply(**{
        'primary': s2_sr_col,
        'secondary': s2_cloudless_col,
        'condition': ee.Filter.equals(**{
            'leftField': 'system:index',
            'rightField': 'system:index'
        })
    }))
```

Cloud masking:

```
def add_cloud_bands(img):
    # Get s2cloudless image, subset the probability band.
    cld_prb = ee.Image(img.get('s2cloudless')).select('probability')

    # Condition s2cloudless by the probability threshold value.
    is_cloud = cld_prb.gt(CLD_PRB_THRESH).rename('clouds')

    # Add the cloud probability layer and cloud mask as image bands.
    return img.addBands(ee.Image([cld_prb, is_cloud]))

def add_shadow_bands(img):
    # Identify water pixels from the SCL band.
    not_water = img.select('SCL').neq(6)

    # Identify dark NIR pixels that are not water (potential cloud shadow pixels).
    SR_BAND_SCALE = 1e4
    dark_pixels = img.select('B8').lt(NIR_DRK_THRESH*SR_BAND_SCALE).multiply(not_water).rename('dark_pixels')

    # Determine the direction to project cloud shadow from clouds (assumes UTM projection).
    shadow_azimuth = ee.Number(90).subtract(ee.Number(img.get('MEAN_SOLAR_AZIMUTH_ANGLE')));

    # Project shadows from clouds for the distance specified by the CLD_PRJ_DIST input.
    cld_proj = (img.select('clouds').directionalDistanceTransform(shadow_azimuth, CLD_PRJ_DIST*10)
        .reproject(**{'crs': img.select(0).projection(), 'scale': 100})
        .select('distance')
        .mask()
        .rename('cloud_transform'))

    # Identify the intersection of dark pixels with cloud shadow projection.
    shadows = cld_proj.multiply(dark_pixels).rename('shadows')

    # Add dark pixels, cloud projection, and identified shadows as image bands.
    return img.addBands(ee.Image([dark_pixels, cld_proj, shadows]))

def add_cld_shdw_mask(img):
    # Add cloud component bands.
    img_cloud = add_cloud_bands(img)

    # Add cloud shadow component bands.
    img_cloud_shadow = add_shadow_bands(img_cloud)

    # Combine cloud and shadow mask, set cloud and shadow as value 1, else 0.
    is_cld_shdw = img_cloud_shadow.select('clouds').add(img_cloud_shadow.select('shadows')).gt(0)

    # Remove small cloud-shadow patches and dilate remaining pixels by BUFFER input.
    # 20 m scale is for speed, and assumes clouds don't require 10 m precision.
    is_cld_shdw = (is_cld_shdw.focalMin(2).focalMax(BUFFER*2/20)
        .reproject(**{'crs': img.select([0]).projection(), 'scale': 20})
        .rename('cloudmask'))

    # Add the final cloud-shadow mask to the image.

    #Keeps 29 bands including the in-between temporary bands for the cloud mask(probability,clouds,dark pixels and shadows).
    return img_cloud_shadow.addBands(is_cld_shdw)
```

Run the 2 functions:

```
s2_sr_cld_col_eval = get_s2_sr_cld_col(aoi, START_DATE, END_DATE)
col = s2_sr_cld_col_eval.map(add_cld_shdw_mask)
```

NDVI calculation and filter:

```
def ndvi_calc(img):
  ndvi = img.normalizedDifference(['B8','B4']).rename('ndvi')
  return img.addBands(ndvi)

#NDVI threshold <0.3
def maskndvi(img):
  ndvi = img.select('ndvi')
  t4= img.updateMask(ndvi.lt(0.3)).updateMask(ndvi.gt(0.0))
  return t4
temp = col.map(ndvi_calc)
col_ndvimask = temp.map(maskndvi)
```